# JQuery ajax - how to send JSON with GET method?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, get

I'm trying to send some data from JQuery.ajax() to my python Flask server, JS code is:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({nickname: "AAA", password: "BBB"});
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    data: data,
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    method: "GET",
    url: "/test_back",
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
});
```

Python code is:

```
@app.route("/test_back", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test_back():
    print(request)
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    return jsonify({})
```

And `print(data)` is writing `None` in console, so I can't read it as a dict.
When I change `method: "GET"` to `method: "POST"`, it works just fine.

So: how do I send JSON from JQuery to Flask, using method GET, correctly?

Comment: Using GET the data is sent as search params in the url. Why do you want to send json in a GET?

Comment: I'm trying to make a RESTful API and I thought that client side should send JSON to server too. Isn't it right?

Comment: I think you should research the differences between how GET and POST work with respect to sending data. While json can be sent in GET search params it is generally not needed

Answer (score 0):

First of all add conditional for flask methods get and post its good practices :D

```
         if request.method == "POST":
         if request.method == "GET":
```

also try return the data not the empty jsonfy

```
return data
```

not

```
return jsonify({})_
```

Comment: I add it on another pages, not on "/test" :D
.json returns None as well D:

Comment: Why are you returning empty jsonify you should just return data you should delete the  return jsonify({}) and return just the data it dosent make sense